# Browsers - Whats the best way to avoid that the user can mark div's

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, selection

I have an image gallery and yes, im aware that the browser standards should be respected for an intuitive user experience. BUT - this blue mark must be avoided in my gallery so that the user can see the image in full beauty. I think javascript could handle this job - but whats the coolest solution (browser compatibilty)?

Thank ya for your response.

Comment: The answer is 42, and that is primarily from a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code:

http://code.jdempster.com/jQuery.DisableTextSelect/jquery.disable.text.select.js

UPDATE: I now realize you did not intend to use jQuery. You can still get the idea from the code, but I also write the details here.

**Firefox**: set -moz-user-select to none (CSS)

**IE**: catch onselectstart and prevent default (JS)

**Other**: catch onmousedown and prevent default (JS)

Comment: Im not really satisfied with this (okay in firefox its very easy to implement)- I will study the jquery plugin. thanks bro'

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery I am using the undocumented method `disableSelection()`:

```
$("div.unselectable").disableSelection();
```

Comment: nope the blue (focus,select,highlight,border or whatever you calling it) stuff is still there

Comment: Ok, forget it... was old and specific code. I edited my answer.